# How can I use a file input and text input all in one form

Tags: html

How can I use a file input and text input all in one form

Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Please share your code so that we can get an understanding of what you are going to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you must be pretty new to html

here is a sample

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label> Name </label>
    <input type="text" name="name">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
```